# \kern after \linebreak doesn't work

Tags: line-breaking, kerning

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent this is good that is food this is good that is food this is good that
is food this is good that is food\linebreak\kern-2em\color{red}\relax this is
good that is food \kern-2em\color{blue}\relax this is good that is food this is
good that is food this is good that is food
\end{document}
```

The second `\kern` works as expected but the first doesn't. Is that because the text is blocked by its left boundary? Is there a way to make `\kern` work after `\linebreak`?

[image]

Comment: note it is not the `\linebreak` command causing this, the same happens at an automatic line break in the same step that drops normal inter-word space if a line break is inserted between words.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your aim, or is it just academic curiosity?

Comment: @egreg My indents were wrong and I was doing some random experiments. The example isn't very meaningful in itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kerns (like glue) are *discardable* so they are dropped at a line break (for the same reason that `\hspace` would be dropped but latex provides `\hspace*`

So you could use `\hspace*{-2em}` or if you really want to use a kern for some reason then `\linebreak\hbox{}\kern-2em` will put a non-discardable box before the kern to prevent it being discarded.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent this is good that is food this is good that is food this is good that
is food this is good that is food\linebreak\kern-2em\color{red}\relax this is
good that is food \kern-2em\color{blue}\relax this is good that is food this is
good that is food this is good that is food

\noindent this is good that is food this is good that is food this is good that
is food this is good that is food\linebreak\hspace*{-2em}\color{red}\relax this is
good that is food \hspace*{-2em}\color{blue}\relax this is good that is food this is
good that is food this is good that is food

\noindent this is good that is food this is good that is food this is good that
is food this is good that is food\linebreak\hbox{}\kern-2em\color{red}\relax this is
good that is food \hbox{}\kern-2em\color{blue}\relax this is good that is food this is
good that is food this is good that is food




\end{document}
```